# Cycle structure in symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, characters

I am studying group representations and to prove that characters from symmetric groups $\chi(g) \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall g \in S_{n}$ I need prove that:

> Consider that $\sigma \in S_{n}$, and $\gcd(m, o(\sigma)) = 1$. Then $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{m}$ has the same cycle structure.

Someone can help me with this question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How is $m$ related to $n$? [In your question only $n$ occurs, but no $m.$]

Comment: @coffeemath The correct is $gdc(m, o(\sigma)) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$If $\tau$ is a cycle of length $k$ in the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma$, then $k \mid o(\sigma)$.

You have thus to prove that if $\gcd(m, k) = 1$, then $\tau^{m}$ is also a cycle of length $k$.

Consider the cyclic subgroup $\Span{\tau}$ of $S_{n}$. Then a standard result shows that $o(\tau^{m}) = o(\tau)$, so that $\Span{\tau} = \Span{\tau^{m}}$. In particular, $\tau$ is a power of $\tau^{m}$. This implies that $\tau^{m}$ is a cycle of length $k$.

Comment: I can't understand why $\tau^{m}$ is a cycle of length k, can you help me?

Comment: To see that $\tau$ is a power of $\tau^{m}$ I used the Bezout theorem

Comment: @JaimeGrimalAlves, if $\tau^{m}$ is a product of smaller cycles, then so is its power $\tau$.